# How to pass a value to a bash script from a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a python script which is performing some logic and it returns an array of strings. This python script is inside a for loop and it gets run twice both times returning an array of strings or empty array.

The python script is being run from a bash script, I would like to inform the bash script that:

```
if python_return_array.count > 0 
then
 echo "Found the following items"
 exit 1
fi
```

I have written the following code:

```
dublicate_keys_present=false

abort()
{
    echo >&2 '
***************
*** ABORTED ***
***************
'
    echo "Found dublicate keys. Exiting..." >&2
    exit 1
}

for folder in ${folders_array[*]}
do  
    for FILE in $FILES
    do
        output=$( python scripts/check_dublicates_swift.py -o "$STRINGS_TMP" "$FILE")
        echo $output
        if [[ some_Int_Value != 0 ]]; then
            $dublicate_keys_present=true
        fi
    done
done

if [ $dublicate_keys_present ]; then
  abort
fi
```

Is it possible to set a int value from python and return it to the bash script. I cant use `sys.exit(1)` because that will terminate the program as soon as a key is found.

Comment: Via files, standard output or standard error output.

Comment: is there any other way other than using a file or logfile to write output to.

Comment: Well, sockets and named pipes are one more option, but that's just files anyway. Why not make your output parseable? I.e. `#number = 123` would be easy to grep and filter. Otherwise... why not just make your script fully Python?

Comment: Is it also possible to show the answer using sockets and named pipes in an example, the only issue is that i dont not want to create a new file

Comment: Why not create a new file? `mktemp` is there for you.

Comment: that can work as long as the file's life cycle can only live through the execution of the program

Comment: Howver i am not very skilled in bash nor python an example of this would help

Comment: But really, is there a reason to mix and match Bash and Python? If you can, you'll have a much easier time having everything in Python.

Comment: these scripts exist for a while already so i cannot change the use of bash and python even-though i would like to. I can only modify the script

Comment: You can make the .sh file a simple wrapper for an all-python script if that's the issue.